# Add an array value (row) to a 2d array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d

I have a int a[10][2] array. Can I assign values in other way like this:

```
int a = someVariableValue;
int b = anotherVariableValue;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
   a[i][0] = a;
   a[i][1] = b;
}
```

like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
   a[i][] = [a,b]; //or something like this
}
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: You may be interested in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays do not have the assignment operator. However you could use an array of `std::array`.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 10;
    std::array<int, 2> a[N];
    int x = 1, y = 2;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i ) a[i] = { x, y };

    for ( const auto &row : a )
    {
        std::cout << row[0] << ' ' << row[1]  << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output is

```
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
1 2
```